# Using js to create a nested list from a json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a sample json file that looks like the following:

```
{
    "PetOwners": [
        {
        "name":"John",
        "age":31,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
            { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
            { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name":"Albert",
        "age":29,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"iquana", "name":"bart" },
            { "animal":"rooster", "name":"Callie" },
            { "animal":"weasel", "name":"Jonathan" }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name":"Sally",
        "age":32,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"cat", "name":"Abbott" },
            { "animal":"bird", "name":"Buzz" },
            { "animal":"rabbit", "name":"Hoppity" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create an HTML list out of these items that would show the pet owners name and an indented list of their pets below their name. I've been able to create a list for the name but how would I create the indented list of the owner's pet under each name? Below is what I have so far.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Reading a JSON file</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Reading a JSON file.</h2>
<ul id="demo"></ul>
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var x = document.getElementById("demo");
            for (i=0; i<myObj.PetOwners.length; i++){
                var opt = myObj.PetOwners[i].name;
                var el = document.createElement("LI");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                x.appendChild(el);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com/json/json_demo.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to stick with pure JavaScript, you can use same approach of `ul and li` in the above for loop.

Comment: Add an inner loop for `myObj.PetOwners[i].pets` and basically do same thing as outer loop that fills up a nested `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
    "PetOwners": [
        {
        "name":"John",
        "age":31,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
            { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
            { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name":"Albert",
        "age":29,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"iquana", "name":"bart" },
            { "animal":"rooster", "name":"Callie" },
            { "animal":"weasel", "name":"Jonathan" }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name":"Sally",
        "age":32,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"cat", "name":"Abbott" },
            { "animal":"bird", "name":"Buzz" },
            { "animal":"rabbit", "name":"Hoppity" }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var html = data["PetOwners"].map(function(owner){
  var res = "<li>" + owner["name"];
  res += "<ul>";
  res += owner["pets"].map(function(pet){
    return "<li>" + pet["name"] + " -> (" + pet["animal"] + ")</li>";
  }).join("");
  return res + "</ul></li>";
});

document.body.innerHTML = html;
// console.log(html);

// Or
 var ul_ = childs => {
 var res = document.createElement("ul");
  childs.forEach( c => res.appendChild(c) );
  return res;
}

var li_ = title => {
 var res = document.createElement("li");
  res.textContent = title;
  return res;
}
var list = ul_( data["PetOwners"].map(function(owner){
  var res = li_(owner["name"]);
  res.appendChild( ul_(owner["pets"].map(function(pet){
    return li_( pet["name"] + " -> " + pet["animal"] );
  }) ) );
  return res;
}) );

document.body.appendChild(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is simple enough. Just repeat the same loop as you did for the outer loop.

Below is the sample for the same.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Reading a JSON file</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Reading a JSON file.</h2>
<ul id="demo"></ul>
<script>

   var myObj = {
    "PetOwners": [
        {
        "name":"John",
        "age":31,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
            { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
            { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name":"Albert",
        "age":29,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"iquana", "name":"bart" },
            { "animal":"rooster", "name":"Callie" },
            { "animal":"weasel", "name":"Jonathan" }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name":"Sally",
        "age":32,
        "pets":[
            { "animal":"cat", "name":"Abbott" },
            { "animal":"bird", "name":"Buzz" },
            { "animal":"rabbit", "name":"Hoppity" }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var outerList = document.createElement('ul');
for (var i=0; i<myObj.PetOwners.length; i++){
    var opt = myObj.PetOwners[i].name;
    var outerListItem = document.createElement("li");
    var innerList = document.createElement('ul');
    for(var j = 0; j < myObj.PetOwners[i].pets.length; j++) {
      var innerListItem = document.createElement('li');
      innerListItem.textContent = myObj.PetOwners[i].pets[j].name;
      innerList.appendChild(innerListItem);
    }
    outerListItem.textContent = opt;
    outerListItem.appendChild(innerList);
    outerList.appendChild(outerListItem);
}

x.appendChild(outerList);

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can repeat the same as another loop

```
            for(pet = 0; pet < myObj.PetOwners[i].pets.length; pet++) {
                var optIn = myObj.PetOwners[i].pets[pet].animal + ":" + myObj.PetOwners[i].pets[pet].name;
                var elIn = document.createElement("LI");
                elIn.className = "tab"
                elIn.textContent = optIn;
                elIn.value = optIn;
                x.appendChild(elIn);
            }
```

adding the below css

```
            <style type="text/css">
                <!--
                .tab { margin-left: 40px; }
                -->
            </style>
```